# DNS fails intermittently in 13.10 after update

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, dns, macbook

After update of the following packages: 
https://gist.github.com/xgdgsc/d52ab6a05adafb152221

I get intermittent DNS failure for less than 1 min every a few minutes. At the same time, other devices are fine connecting the net, so it is not the router' s problem. And the Mac OS X on this Macbook pro (2011 late with broadcom wireless) is also fine without such problem. I tried downgrading linux-firmware but not working. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the package according to 
https://zoni.nl/posts/2013/11/09/fixing-the-broadcom-bcm4331-wireless-drivers-on-ubuntu-1310/
seem to fix this issue.